# "$env" >| /dev/null , what is the redirection sign and the pipeline doing here?

Tags: bash

This command is from https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases#auto-launching-ssh-agent-on-git-for-windows , the section of "Auto-launching ssh-agent on Git for Windows" .
For a single redirection sign followed by a device , i know what it is doing .
For a single pipe line , i know what it is doing.
When they are together , i'm confused !! Could anyone explain "$env" >| /dev/null ?? why ">|" ?

Answer (score 2):

There is a `noclobber` option [in set](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin):

> The noclobber option is available to avoid overwriting existing files with output redirection (see The Set Builtin). The ‘>|’ redirection operator may be used to override noclobber.

And [redirecting output in bash manual documents it](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirecting-Output):

> If the redirection operator is ‘>’, and the noclobber option to the set builtin has been enabled, the redirection will fail if the file whose name results from the expansion of word exists and is a regular file. If the redirection operator is ‘>|’, or the redirection operator is ‘>’ and the noclobber option is not enabled, the redirection is attempted even if the file named by word exists.

But I think [greg's wiki explains noclobber more clearly](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/NoClobber).